# dismiss currently presented and show specific ViewController on app resume

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller

I am newbie and developing a single view application for iPhone with various (**A**, **B**, **C**, **D**) view controller. Root view controller is **A** and other view controller are presented as

> [self presentModalViewController:**C** animated:YES];
>   on some button click.

If the application suspends at **C** or any other view due to phone call or home button or any action and on resume i want to dismiss presented view (**C** or **D** or any) and present **B** .

What should i code? (on appDelegate.m) or Where??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `AppDelegate` method:

**Update**

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was
    //inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [self.viewController dismissAnyViewController];
    [self.viewController representBmodelViewController];
}
```

Implement these two method in your `viewContoller`, the first one for dismssing any `viewController` you are present by using

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

then present your desired `viewController`.

Read the comment inside the method to understand what does it do.

Comment: How to dismiss the  currently displaying viewController and present other. Could you please provide some code??

Comment: send `[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` to any controller that is modal.  This means you would have to track each controller in the AppDelegate, which would be considered bad practice.  Better to dismiss in the controller itself, probably by tracking the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notification.